# InstallTapOnBus - for output signal

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudioengine

As in topic subject, I want to analyze buffer of the output signal. I've used this function ( InstallTapOnBus ) for microphone signal, but i does not work for output. Anyone know how do that?

```
    let bus = 0 
    let node = engine.outputNode
    node.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(BUFFER_SIZE), format: node.outputFormat(forBus: bus), block: { (buffer : AVAudioPCMBuffer ,time : AVAudioTime) in

        ...

    })
    try! engine.start()
}
```

It provides me an error : "required condition is false: _isInput"

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried tapping the mixer instead of the microphone directly?

[image: Microphone-to-mixer-to-output with Mixer Tap]

Answer (score 2):

Try `mainMixerNode` instead of outputNode.

This worked for me (iOS 12):

`let outputNode = self.audioEngine.mainMixerNode
let format = self.audioEngine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)`

Then installTap on mainMixerNode like you did.